# how to make it to write the total and not showing it in a input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making this calculator on javascript with html and i have it working already i just want to input the total in plain text and not in the input box i have right now....

the JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Eliasperez/PDct2/1/

```
<div>Producto
<br />
<select id="producto1">
    <option>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="01">Curativo</option>
    <option value="02">Preventiva</option>
</select>
</div>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="e01">
        <td class="01">
            <label>Cantidad</label>
            <br />
            <select id="elias">
                <option value="1">1 Gr/m3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="02">
            <label>Cantidad</label>
            <br />
            <select id="elias1">
                <option value=".33">.33 Gr/m3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="container">
<div>
    <label for="CAT_Custom_500436">Cual es el volumen del area a tratar por metro      cúbico? </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_500436" id="CAT_Custom_500436" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="CAT_Custom_500440">Total</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_500440" id="CAT_Custom_500440" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="error hide">Porfavor escoje un producto 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Replace you input <input type = "text" maxlength = "25 name = "CAT_Custom_500440" id = "CAT_Custom_500440" / >

  with this span:
   <span id='totalValue'></span>

    And use this code then:

 $(document).ready(function () {
 / / Cache the variables
  var $elias = $('#elias'),
      $elias1 = $('#elias1'),
      $elias2 = $('#elias2'),
      $product = $('#producto1'),
      $error = $('.error'),
      $container = $('.container');
  $("td").hide();
  var productValue;
  $product.change(function () {
      $(".e01 td").hide();
      $("td." + $(this).val()).show();
      // Only show the container when the selections are not first 2
      if (this.value !== 'Selecciona' && this.value !== '00') {
          $error.addClass('hide');
          $container.removeClass('hide');
      } else {
          $error.removeClass('hide');
          $container.addClass('hide');
      }
      productValue = this.value;
  }).change();
   // Bind the change event for Dropdowns
  var $quantity = $('#CAT_Custom_500436'),
      $total = $("#totalValue");

  $elias.add($elias1).add($elias2).change(findTotal);
  $quantity.keyup(findTotal);

  function findTotal() {
      // Get the value
      var quan = $quantity.val();
      var pri = $('.' + productValue).find('select').val();
      var tot = pri * quan;
      var toto = tot + " Gr de Fumispore";
      $total.text(toto);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick an element and set the total as the text:

Create a div/span or something with id `total`, and then:

`$('#total').text( total );`

Comment: If it's just one element you should use an ID rather than class.

Comment: i create a div with the id totaland the code you put is for the javascript i made? can you make me a example through jsfiddle since im already lost, if its not too much trouble please.

Comment: Wherever you're defining the total now, add the code above. The code snippet just takes your total and sets it as the text value of the `#total` div